# What kind of visa do I need to have a temporary job in London?

Tags: united-kingdom, visa, working-visas, eu-spouses

I'm Syrian and I have a student residence permission to EU issued from Portugal.

I got a job offer for 6 months in London.

The company asked me to have a sponsor. I do have someone in the UK to sponsor me, but I don't know how the process works.

I was checking the types of visas and I found this page https://www.gov.uk/browse/visas-immigration/work-visas

I don't know to which one I have to apply, or if I need something else to prof that I have a sponsor

Could you help please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to check myself.

I need visa either Tier 2 or Tier 5, as described here http://www.workpermit.com/uk/uk-immigration-tier-system.htm

The sponsor must be a licensed sponsor employer, which can be found here

https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/register-of-licensed-sponsors-workers

(the list and the link is being updated daily)